# Sending long JSON via POST Python

Tags: python, json

I know this seems fundamental, but how do we do it? For example,

```
import urllib2
import ssl
import requests
import json

SetProxy={'https':'https://sample.sample.com'}
proxy = urllib2.ProxyHandler(SetProxy)
url="https://something.com/getsomething"
opener = urllib2.build_opener(proxy)
urllib2.install_opener(opener)
payload = {
  "uaaURL": "https://com-example.something.com",
  "sampleID": "admin",
  "sampleSecret": "password",
  "sampleID2": "example-sample-el",
  "sampleSecret2": "ssenjsoemal/+11=",
  "username": "test",
  "someAttributes": {
    "Groups": [
      "example_com-abc"
    ],
    "attribute": [
      "value1"
    ]
  }
}

req = urllib2.Request(url)
req.add_header('Content-Type','application/json')
response = urllib2.urlopen(req, json=json.dumps(payload))
```

The above runs and gives me a 400 which means my JSON is bad. I was not able to find a post that sent large JSON data via a post request. Any advice? Thanks!

Comment: How are you handling this in your API? 400 usually implies that JSON is invalid according to the API specifications.

Comment: The JSON format should comply exactly with the format I've assigned to my payload (spaces and all). Then the API accepts it.

Answer (score -1):

try to use below :

```
import json

import urllib2

import ssl

import requests

SetProxy={'https':'https://sample.sample.com'}

proxy = urllib2.ProxyHandler(SetProxy)

url='https://something.com/getsomething'

opener = urllib2.build_opener(proxy)

urllib2.install_opener(opener)

data = {
  'uaaURL' : 'https://com-example.something.com',
  'sampleID': 'admin',
  'sampleSecret': 'password',
  'sampleID2': 'example-sample-el',
  'sampleSecret2': 'ssenjsoemal/+11=',
  'username': 'test',
  'someAttributes': {
    'Groups': ['example_com-abc' ],
    'attribute': [ 'value1' ]
  }

req = urllib2.Request('https://something.com/getsomething')

req.add_header('Content-Type', 'application/json')

response = urllib2.urlopen(req, json.dumps(data))
```

Comment: Ok then try this with double quotes

Comment: What have you changed though? I can't find the change?

Comment: Izy first can you try to hit your webservice using rest client (a chrome app) and prepare the json object there and then give that json payload to me.

Comment: JSON always uses double quotes. Look at the output of `json.dumps({'a':'a'})`.

Comment: @EkantSharma, the format I've given in my post is exactly how the API accepts.

Comment: can't you debug the code in any IDE and see how json string is formed in sending request there must be something wrong with the json payload formation in the request you sending.See what exactly the difference json.dumps(data) returning and the json which is working fine.